Error in linking SQL Server and MS Access databases using SSMS
I was trying to create a live link to access database using Access linked server.

SSMS version 19.3
Office 365

Please help to resolve this error.
The SQL statement used:
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
            @server = 'AccessLinkedServer', -- The name of the linked server
            @srvproduct = '', -- Product name (leave blank for Access)
            @provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', -- The OLE DB provider for Access
            @datasrc = 'C:\NEST\NEST Bill Temp_be.accdb'; -- The path to the Access database file

-- Test the linked server connection
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(AccessLinkedServer, 
               'SELECT * FROM RGEtblPromotions').

Error:

Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" has not been registered.


Not sure what else I need to do.
Microsoft Access database Engine 2016 (64 & 32 bits have been installed).
I also tried to register Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 through command window. Error occur again.

You did install the 64bit driver on the host that SQL Server is running on, right? Installing it on your PC won't help as, presumably, the servixe is on a different host. Did you restart the service after installing it?
